# How can I replace a from value using a cookie?

Tags: php, html

I want to use cookies to remember the usernames I add and replace the default value with the last used username.
I have the following html code:

```
<link href = "login.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
    
        <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value ="?" name="uname" required>
    
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
    
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is login.php:

```
<?php
echo("Success!");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    setcookie("username", $_POST["uname"], time()+30*24*60*60);
}
?>
```

I want to replace the '?' from

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value ="?" name="uname" required>
```

with the value held by the cookie.

This is what I do in value.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["username"]))
    echo $_COOKIE["username"];
?>
```

Can I do something like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value ="value.php" name="uname" required>
```

so I don't have to write the php code there? This doesn't work, the value I get in the form is "value.php"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not read the username from the cookie and print it wherever you want to print it?

Comment: I also tried to just add the code after value = but it doesn't recognize it. Does it have something to do with the first file?(it is called login.html)

Comment: Please share your attempts. `value ="value.php"` does not look like you are evaluating any PHP code

Comment: Please have a look at the setcookie function: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php. To set the cookie there is no previous output allowed. Try removing `echo`

Comment: I also tried removing the quote and also removing the echo, none worked. In the username field in the form I get whatever I add after value = , in my case the php code.

Comment: @Fisher No, I mean in the login.php file. Did You check, if the cookie is ever set?

Comment: @ivion Yes, the cookie is set.

Comment: @Fisher Does `value ="<?php echo $_COOKIE["username"]; ?>"` work?

Comment: @ivion No , in value I get the text <?php echo $_COOKIE[ , the rest is added to the next line.

Comment: Does the file containing the login form has the ending .html and perhaps isn't parsed by php?

Comment: Yes, I said in the second comment, the file is named login.html

Comment: Normally these files aren't parsed by php. Try to rename to `login_form.php`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with PHP, but can't you just do:

```php
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value="<?php include 'value.php'?>" name="uname" required>
```

or something like that?

Comment: Please share more details - why do you need to include a file just to print out a value from the cookies array?

Comment: @NicoHaase because your if statement is in value.php, we need to get to it in some way and in order to do that, you need to import it which will then echo the value of username, the cookie

Comment: I want to do this with a simple code, next time I might need to have a more complex algorithm there. I'm just trying to separate the html from php code.